# optimizing javascript for src tags

Tags: javascript, optimization, src

I have a list of javascript calls for a page such as:

```
<!-- page scripts -->
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.chosen.min.js"></script> <!-- not used but we should     -->
<script src="/js/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script><!--used-->
<script src="/js/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.inputlimiter.1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.hotkeys.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/jquery.knob.modified.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/justgage.1.0.1.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"      src="/js/js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui-sliders-progress.js"></script>

<!-- inline scripts related to this page -->
<script src="/js/pages/form-elements.js"></script><!--used-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/stripe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

How can I possibly optimize this and make my pages faster

Comment: Remove all the plugins you're not actively using on the page. Minify the rest into a single file called "plugins.js" and call that instead.

Comment: find plugins on CDN and link them instead using yours

Comment: Combine your JS files in to one (or multiple ones, it depends on how big they are) and [minify your code](http://jscompress.com/) for it to be lighter.

Comment: Set up proper cache management on your server so that the plugin files are cached locally by the browser and only downloaded infrequently thereafter.